# Login servlet which returns user's name after validating login details

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am a beginner and I want to create a login servlet that will validate the user's data and return their full name.

I have everything working except for displaying the user's full name from the data base.

Should I do this in the login servlet or in the jsp?
If I do it in the JSP how to I get it to only display one full name instead of the whole table.

Here is the relevent code in the servlet.
Is there any way to display the first_name and last_name which where queried?

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select first_name, last_name from userdata where user_name = ? and password = ?");

            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, passwd);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();


            if (rs.next()) {


                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);

//out.println(rs.getString(2));
             } else {

                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("tryagain.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of first name and last name in the request

```
if (rs.next()) {
             request.setAttribute("fname",rs.getString("Firstname");
             request.setAttribute("lname",rs.getString("Latname");            
             RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
             rd.include(request, response);
 }
```

jsp page code

```
 <% 
   <%= request.getAttribute("fname") %>
   <%= request.getAttribute("lname") %>
 %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I added your code but netbeans is red lining the setAttribute. Is there something I need to import?

Comment: No need to import check the request object and set the index or column name in rs.getString()

Comment: I did set the column name it's still red lining. It says it can't find symbol

Comment: try to set the the column index

Answer (score 1):

One way is by using `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`
retrieve the username from the database and store it using `setAttribute();`

```
setAttribute("username","username");
```

to display it in jsp get it using `getAttribute();`

```
getAttribute("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you seperate the data base Class from the Servlet calss.
Make Seperate Class for Database.

And in order to transfer the data from servlet to JSP
Use request.setAttribute("objectName", object Value);